# Laravel how to display day and month only without year from date type?

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-9

I would wan to display month and data for payment_date only in a foreach loop in view.blade.php.

```
  @foreach ($alert as $key=>$data)
          <tr>
             <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
             <td>{{ $data->tenant_name}}</td>
             <td>{{ $data->property_name}}</td>
             <td>RM {{ $data->amount}}</td>
             <td>{{ $data->payment_date }}</td>
             <td><span class="badge bg-danger">{{ $data->status }}</span></td>                                       
             <td><a href="{{ route('view.email', $data->tenant->id) }}" class="btn icon btn-primary sm"  title="Send Email"> <i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i> </a>
             </td>
          </tr>
   @endforeach
```

[image]

Hereby I include the datatype:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short way  (not recommended)**

```
@foreach ($alert as $key=>$data)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->tenant_name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->property_name}}</td>
        <td>RM {{ $data->amount}}</td>
        <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $data->payment_date)->format('m-d') }}</td>
        <td><span class="badge bg-danger">{{ $data->status }}</span></td>                                       
        <td><a href="{{ route('view.email', $data->tenant->id) }}" class="btn icon btn-primary sm"  title="Send Email"> <i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i> </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**Laravel way (Recommended)**

Add cast to the eloquent model class.

```
protected $casts = [
    'payment_date' => 'date',
];
```

after that you can do this

```
@foreach ($alert as $key=>$data)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->tenant_name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->property_name}}</td>
        <td>RM {{ $data->amount}}</td>
        <td>{{ $data->payment_date->format('m-d') }}</td>
        <td><span class="badge bg-danger">{{ $data->status }}</span></td>                                       
        <td><a href="{{ route('view.email', $data->tenant->id) }}" class="btn icon btn-primary sm"  title="Send Email"> <i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i> </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```